# Show that $\log$ is a logarithm on $\mathbb{C}_-$ and check that it coincides with $\sum_{1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n(z-1)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{C}_- = \{z\in \mathbb{C} \;|\; Re(z) > 0 \}$

Define $\log : \mathbb{C}_- \to \mathbb{C} $ given by $z = |z|e^{i\theta} \mapsto \ln |z| + i\theta$ where $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi)$

Show that $\log$ is a logarithm on $\mathbb{C}_-$ and check that in $D_1(1) \subset \mathbb{C}_-$ it coincides with $\sum_{1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n(z-1)^n$

To show that $\log $ is a logarithms on $\mathbb{C}_-$, I will show that $\exp(\log(z)) = z$ where $z = |z|e^{i\theta}$

$\exp(\log(z)) = \exp(\ln |z| + i\theta) = |z|exp(i\theta) = z $

How can I show the second part? I have no idea how to show the second part

Comment: if $f(z)=\sum_{1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n(z-1)^n$ in the given domain, what is $f'(z)$ and what is $(\log z)'$?

Comment: I really don't know what is $f'(z)$ here

Comment: $f'(z)=\sum_{1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}(z-1)^{n-1}$ so it's a geometric series with $z-1=w$ etc

Comment: Ok so $f'(z) = \frac{1}{1-(1-z)} = \frac{1}{z} = (\log z)'$ So these two coincides since $ f'(z) = \frac1z$ is characteristic of $\log(z)$

Comment: correct and now if you show that $f(1)=0$ (obvious of course) you are good since if two analytic functions satisfy $(f-g)'=0$ on a connected open set, $f-g=C$ and then $C=0$ since $\log 1=0$ too

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: happy to be of help